# How to create Entity file in Swift in iOS programming?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, swift

I want to use Core Data in my iOS app which is based on Swift and Xcode 6, so I first created `XXX.xcdatamodel` file and added three entities and its attributes to the file. However, when I tried to create a subclass of `NSManagedObject` by following "Editor" | "Create ManagedObject subclass" in Xcode menu, the resultant files are Objective-C's `.h` and `.m` file, not `.swift` file that I want.

As a result, when I tried to run the simulator, I got an error: `NSFetchRequest could not locate an NSEntityDescription for entity name 'XXX'`, which I think is because there are no such `.swift` file as `XXX` in my project.

So how can I create a subclass of `NSManagedObject` which is based on the entity defined in the `XXX.xcdatamodel` file above? I don't like the idea of creating a new swift file and writing those attributes one-by-one manually, since the number of attribute on each entity is more than 40. So I rather want to create it automatically, by something like the Xcode menu which I've used in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In objective-c, the code would look somewhat like below:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface Human : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@end
```

Above is the .h and below is the .m

```
#import "Human.h"

@implementation Human
@dynamic name;
@end
```

As stated in the documentation, swift deals with all of the underlying components so it is actually very easy to convert.

```
import Cocoa

class Human: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var name : NSString

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I did was I used generated .h and .m files. To make entity classes visible for swift add #import for your headers of entity classes to Bridging Header.

Comment: That's what I first tried, but still got the same error.

Comment: Can you do NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("EntityName", inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext) ?